# Need to join 3 tables and return results where everyone is over age 75

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table employee with
id, name, dob, emplid

table documentation has
cdid, emplid, status, record

table appointment has
cvid, emplid, slotid

Everyone has a record in table Employee. Table Appointment stores everyone who schedules an appointment and table Documentation is where the record gets inserted when they complete their appointment. The problem is, they take walk-ins and will have a record in table Documentation, but no record in table Appointment. They want me to find everyone in table Employee who is over age 75, but does not currently have an appointment or has never come in as a walk-in.

I started with the below, but I am stuck on how to accurately get everyone counted.

```
SELECT COUNT(AgeYearsIntTrunc) 
FROM ( 
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,e.DOB,GETDATE())/8766.0 AS AgeYearsDecimal
    ,CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,e.DOB,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS AgeYearsIntRound
    ,DATEDIFF(hour,e.DOB,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
FROM [dbo].Employee e 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].Documentation d ON e.EmplID = d.EMPLID 
WHERE d.Status IS NULL
) dt WHERE AgeYearsIntTrunc >='75'
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIJvB.png)

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: Where in "find everyone ..." does it say "count"? What is the logical meaning of "does not currently have an appointment **or** has never come in as a walk-in"? Aside: `AgeYearsIntTrunc >='75'` seems like a curious place to use a literal string value (`'75'`).

Comment: _has never come in as a walk-in_ Without DDL for your tables it is dangerous to guess how this fact can be determined. The same is true for _not currently have an appointment_. So start with posting the DDL for your tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally best to not expect the compiler to do algebra for you, in other words: write predicates like `x > y + 5` rather than `x - y > 5`.

Generally, the most efficient method for comparing dates is to keep the column you are checking without any function, do any necessary calculations on the `GETDATE` side.

`NOT EXISTS` is much easier for the compiler to reason about than `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

```sql
SELECT e.*  --COUNT(*) 
FROM [dbo].Employee e 
WHERE e.DOB < DATEADD(year, -75, GETDATE())
AND (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].Documentation d
        WHERE e.EmplID = d.EMPLID 
    )
    AND   -- do you want OR maybe?
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Appointment a
        WHERE a.EmplId = e.EmplId
    )
)
```